# Calculating the SUM of a column values multiplied on weight coefficient (only if the coefficient exists) in Google Spreadsheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a table like this:
[image: google sheet with sum]

There are a Values column and optional weight coefficients.
If Weight is not set, then Value should not be added to the sum.

In the example, the sum should be: (8 * 0.5) + (6 * 0.3) = 5.8

What is the formula for the B2 cell?

Something like SUM(A * IF(B is set, then B, else 0))

I looked into SUMPRODUCT and SUMIF, but still have no idea how should it be applied.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With [SUMPRODUCT](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094294):

```
=SUMPRODUCT(A5:A8,B5:B8)
```

[image]